# I would like to let it be a click element with link tag in react, but I have problems with css

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make a website in local using React.
It is my codes, I surrounded those two elements with a div tag and applied border css looking like related elements, but when I applied a Link tag to go to another page to the div elements, the border started not surrounding under the element. In shortly, how can I use the css file that before apply Link tag?

Here is my code.

```css
div{
        border: 1px black solid;
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
    }

.p {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<Link to='/tests/'>
    <div>
        <i class='fas fa-check fa-5x'></i>
        <p>take tests</p>
    </div>
<Link>
```

Comment: You're opening `<Link>` tag and ending it with `<List>` instead of `</Link>` or maybe you're not showing the whole code

Comment: Thank your comment, it was a mistake that typing the post.

Comment: If you put a dot in the CSS, you're selecting the class, not the element, you're selecting an element like that `<div class="div"></div>` with your CSS

Comment: Your question is virtually unreadable. Please fix the grammer/language issues so that we can help you.

Comment: `a` elements are inline by default, try to apply `display: block` or `inline-block`. (Using a `p` element for a CTA-like text is still a bad choice though, IMHO. That is everything but a _paragraph_ of running text …)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a class to the div and fix your CSS.

```
.tests{
        border: 1px black solid;
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
    }

.p {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

The jsx

```
<Link to='/tests/' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
    <div className="tests">
        <i class='fas fa-check fa-5x'></i>
        <p>take tests</p>
    </div>
<Link>
```

Comment: Don't really know if it changes something, my code editor is always underlining my code if I do this but if there's no element you can do this : `<i class='fas fa-check fa-5x' />` and close the tag by itself